# Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I am  using httpmime and httpcore in my project and I am getting this warning

> Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is
>   ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.
>
> Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is
>   ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version
>   provided by Android.

my dependencies look like this

```
dependencies {    
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/classes.jar')
    compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
    compile files('libs/splunk-mint-4.2.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'}
```

As suggested in other places I added this to my build.gradle file

```
packagingOptions {
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'}
```

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use repacked version of the apache http client suitable for android

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/android-port.html

Comment: How can I import it on MainActivity? I have to use NameValuePair from import org.apache.http

Answer (score 11):

**Firstly remove the lines** 

    `compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.4.1'`

then at their place **add the lines** in build.gradle given by:

```
compile ('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'){
    exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient'
}
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
```

You can try this if your compileSdkVersion is 19(IN MY CASE) more preferably. Hope this will resolve the issue...

Answer (score 8):

**Solution 1**

I know this is so late but i'm posting here because accepted answer was not working for me

previously i used

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

then i got the warning like question after that i commented some lines like bellow

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
    //compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.3.2'
    //compile files('libs/httpclient-4.2.1.jar')
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
}
```

now everything working fine

**Edit**

**Solution 2**

I got the best process than previous

add [httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ph1c4ljnneqhwct/httpcore-4.3-beta1.jar?dl=0) and [httpmime-4.3.jar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uv5fuz610o2e7r5/httpmime-4.3.jar?dl=0) in lib's folder and finally add

`useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in your graddle file (Inside of android) as like bellow

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    //For http
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.videorotation"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
        ......
}
```

Comment: Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5 is ignored for release as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android..........................still giving these warnings.

Comment: @King While you doing are commented previous http related dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Solution：
add useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
configurations {
    all*.exclude module: 'httpclient'
}

I think some people may need this，

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

If you have kept the below one :-,

```
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , 
name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```

change it to this,

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
```