# twilio Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6 is ignored for debug

Tags: java, android, apache, twilio

I've seen many questions about this, but none of them are working.

```
compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:5.10.0'
```

This is the Twilio dependency I'm using. Using that, I get this warning:

> Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.6
>   is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal
>   version provided by Android.

My gradle dependencies:

```
compile('com.h6ah4i.android.widget.advrecyclerview:advrecyclerview:0.9.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.2'
compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:recyclerview-multiselect:0.2'
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${firebaseVersion}"
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.0.2'
compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.3.0'
compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:${firebaseVersion}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:${firebaseVersion}"
compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.1'
compile 'com.novoda:merlin:0.8.0'
compile 'biz.kasual:materialnumberpicker:1.2.1'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:0.4.3'
compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
compile 'com.yqritc:recyclerview-flexibledivider:1.4.0'
compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:${firebaseVersion}"
compile 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:${firebaseVersion}"
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${firebaseVersion}"
compile "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:${supportLibVersion}"
testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4'
"compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4'
compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.1'
compile 'com.github.Commit451:NativeStackBlur:1.0.5'
compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.2.2'
compile project(':MaterialSearchView')
compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.5'
compile group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio-java-sdk', version: '7.0.0-rc-10'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755989/dependency-org-apache-httpcomponentshttpclient4-4-1-is-ignored-for-release-as

Comment: @siva35 didn't work

Comment: @siva35 at least the accepted answer didn't work. The other answer might work, but won't excluding the dependency make twilio unresponsive?

Comment: did you tried latest version of TWILIO SDK?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twilio.sdk/twilio-java-sdk/7.0.0-rc-10

Comment: @siva35 that dependency is from the twilio site, so I'm guessing it's the latest

Comment: Latest version 7.0.  compile group: 'com.twilio.sdk', name: 'twilio-java-sdk', version: '7.0.0-rc-10'

Comment: @siva35 still have the warning

Comment: post your gradle file