# While rebuilding my project warning about httpcomponents is shown

Tags: android, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

While rebuilding my project i encountered this warning

```
Warning:WARNING: Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.0.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
```

here is my gradle.build in which i have tried adding the stated solutions in given link but the problem still persists.So what should i do?

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
// tried this but no help
// useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.0"
    resConfigs "en_US", "hi_IN"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
}

 }
   dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
//tried this but no help
  // compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.1.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

[Question reffered for solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755989/dependency-org-apache-httpcomponentshttpclient4-4-1-is-ignored-for-release-as)

Comment: is this `build.gradle` complete or redacted? and is there any dependency in `libs` dir?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after removing this dependency completely from my project

```
compile 'io.kickflip:sdk:1.3.1'
```

and also from my libs dir.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: the issue is about something else

Add the dependency like this:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

From here: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client

Comment: I have already tried this but no success,the warning still appears.